# mysql Database lookup using wso2esb or wso2-am

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Just as the title suggests.
I want to wrap a database call in an API or REST API whichever is easiest preferable API Manager API.

How can i do this and return the data from the database in json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DSS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/WSO2+Data+Services+Server+Documentation) to access the database, and then a payload factory mediator or Data Mapper to transform the response in a json.
Alternatively, you can use DSS to expose your data as a set of REST style resource.Take a look at this [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS322/Exposing+Data+as+REST+Resources) for an example on how to achieve this.

Comment: I managed to create a data service. I dont think this is hosted as a REST API it is a soap service is it not?

Comment: i realised the resource part of setting a data service is the REST API part. how could i invoke this rest api via HTML code. i have tried alot of methods with no success.